# How to create .ts components in Vue?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have an old project I need to update that uses 'av-ts' plugin to create class style components with vue-ts-loader to compile .ts files as vue components. The project currently runs on vue 2.4.2 but I want to update to 2.6.14. Since 'vue-ts-loader' is depricated and the project breaks after updating to ^2.5 I need an alternative way to compile the files.

I wonder if there is a way to configure the regular ts-loader to do that for me. Anyone have an idea?

Components currently look like this:

```
import { Component, p, Prop } from 'av-ts';
import * as Vue from 'vue';

@Component({
  template: require('./example-component.component.html')
})
export default class ExampleComponent extends Vue {
  @Prop public icon: any = p({
    type: String,
    required: false,
    default: ''
  });

  @Prop public width: any = p({
    type: Number,
    required: false,
    default: 24
  });

  @Prop public height: any = p({
    type: Number,
    required: false,
    default: 24
  });

  @Prop public classes: any = p({
    type: String,
    required: false,
    default: ''
  });
}
```

Comment: I use the VuePropertyDecorator together with the VueClassComponent libraries, through a CDN. So, through a script included in your head tag. It allows me to compile my typescript files with the regular `tsc` compiler. There won't be a bundle created though. Only seperate .js files.

Comment: Could you show me what the script looks like? Also would I import the properties from VueClassComponent or VuePropertyDecorator? Thanks!

Comment: Here you've a simple app, where all libraries are loaded through CDN scripts: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-2bruat?file=index.ts. Running `tsc` will compile all `.ts` files to `.js`. If you do want to bundle through webpack, you can. Then you don't have to load the libraries through cdn.

Answer (score 1):

In the worst case. We could not use SFC with ts. Due to `vue-class-component` is [deprecated in vue3](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/issues/569).There is a alternative one in vue3.[vue-facing-decorator](https://github.com/facing-dev/vue-facing-decorator).It shows how to [write component with regular ts file](https://facing-dev.github.io/vue-facing-decorator/#/en/quick-start/quick-start?id=in-separated-files-with-tsx).

Comment: That is actually very helpful, thanks for sharing. So you say I could potentially go directly from 2.4 to 3.x using the package? I think my biggest issue is that the project I am working on uses webpack and I don't know how to configure the loader and how to make everything work together in general. I am so bad with anything webpack related.

Comment: @Pazulay vue-facing-decorator is easy to use if you have ts decorators experience. It's only designed for vue 3.x. Either your project is created by vue-cli with webpack or vite, vue-facing-decorator should work well directly.